# How to make Multilist component allow only one item selected?

Tags: codenameone

How to make CodeNameOne Multilist component allow only one item selected each time and show a Radiobutton in each item to point this selection?

A list with RadioButton behavior.

IMPORTANT:
I need to do that programmatically (without using GUI-Builder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate the underlying `MultiButton` components in the renderers. Try this:

```
MultiButton unsel = myMultiList.getUnselectedButton();
MultiButton sel = myMultiList.getSelectedButton();
unsel.setRadioButton(true);
sel.setRadioButton(true);
```

To get the behavior to actually be an "exclusive" behavior the model needs to only allow a single selection (FYI this will be **WAY WAY WAY** simpler with just using `MultiButton` in a `Container` and avoiding `MultiList` altogether).

Bind an action listener to the list and whenever the selection changes remove the "selected" attribute from the previously selected entry and then let the default behavior select the new entry.

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify that

Comment: The answer suggests two approaches:
The first one (where a piece of code was shown) didn't resolve the problem. This approach remains allowing selection of multiple items.
The second approach resolves the problem. Using other composition of visual components. Other way to accomplish the goal.